# How to run ASP.NET Core on arm-based custom linux?

Tags: asp.net-core, arm, .net-core, embedded-linux

I want to build an ASP.NET Core Web API service to run on an [arm (cortex-A7) device](https://www.toradex.com/de/computer-on-modules/colibri-arm-family/nxp-freescale-imx7) with an [angstrom](http://%20www.angstrom-distribution.org) based linux.

**Question:** What is the best route to follow?

1. Compile CoreClr, CoreFx, and what-not for the arm7 device (could be [possible](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/3977), but I'm not sure about the angstrom linux). If that works, published bytecode should run on that device.
2. cross-compile my aspnet app using dotnet native and target arm. I couldn't find useful infos but it could be possible.
3. Something else? Like generate C++ code from my project?
4. Compile a different linux distro for the device (probably a no-go since we need IPC between the Linux Cortex-A7 CPU and the FreeRTOS Cotex-M4 CPU).

My main concern is the angstrom distribution, which is not supported by dotnet core out of the box. Any advice is welcome!

---

**Edit, Open Questions:**

- Where can I download the correct pre-built dotnet binaries for an Cortex-A7 (I could not get https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup to work)?
- What other prerequisites do I need (if any)?

Comment: Did you try running the pre-built arm build of .net core? e.g. with the 2.0 preview 1?

Comment: I just learned that core 2.0 is available and that "linux" as a target replaces those many distros. However, I can't find pre-built arm version. Directions are welcome.

Comment: I found a build "Linux (armhf) (for glibc based OS)" on https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup - not sure if "armhf" fits the Cortex-A7. Gonna try next week.

Comment: wrote an answer with steps, but there may be some prerequisites you might need to install, but I can't find a good prerequisites document to link to so I asked in https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/640#issuecomment-301236162

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, forget about angstrom. You will not get any of the native dependencies from that distro or its package manager. Neither will you find any useful resources for angstrom.

Instead, use [yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) to build your own [OpenEmbedded Core](https://www.openembedded.org/wiki/OpenEmbedded-Core) linux distro and *add native dependencies during the build*. At the time of writing, this can be managed with the [meta-aspnet layer](https://github.com/Tragetaschen/meta-aspnet) from [Tragetaschen](https://github.com/Tragetaschen). The `readme.md` states mono as a requirement, which is not true (anymore?).

Once the native dependencies (libunwind, libicu, and many more) are available on the arm system, you can download the latest `Linux (armhf) (for glibc based OS)` build from https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup, unpack it into `/opt/dotnet/`, and create a symlink via `ln -s /opt/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/`. This is the OP's solution number 1 and generic bytecode projects (just `dotnet publish`) will work fine.

If you don't like to install dotnet on the target machine, you can compile for `-r linux-arm` (Martin Ulrich's suggestion), which produces a huge publish folder including coreclr and corefx. However, installing dotnet on the target machine is the smallest of all problems and separating your app from dotnet coreclr/fx/host is cleaner (imho).

The key problems are

1. Which dependencies are required? There is no clear answer, yet.
2. How to compile them for your machine?

The `meta-aspnet` layer seems to solve both problems (at the time of writing). You'll have to dig into it for more details or just use it as is.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the portable `linux-arm` runtime build of .NET Core.
On your build machine, make sure that `dotnet --version` returns a `2.0`, preview, or higher version (at the time of writing: `2.0.0-preview1-005977`).

1. `dotnet new mvc`
2. `dotnet restore -r linux-arm`
3. `dotnet publish -r linux-arm /p:MvcRazorCompileOnPublish=false`
4. Copy the contents of `bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/linux-arm/publish` to your target machine and run with `./nameOfTheProject`

Since you probably want to develop locally as well, you'd want to edit the project (`.csproj`) file like this (`<PropertyGroup>`):

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-arm</RuntimeIdentifiers>
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish Condition=" '$(RuntimeIdentifier)' != 'linux-arm' ">true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
```

This way you can use both `dotnet restore`, `dotnet run` and `dotnet publish` during development or other deploys without additional parameters and when ready to deploy to arm, only use:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-arm
```

and use the resulting binaries from `bin/Release/netcoreapp2.0/linux-arm/publish` (or pass an additional `-o ../publish-output` argument)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Martin Ulrichs suggestions I had partial success in cross-compiling a self-contained executable for arm. The code is cross-compiled on a `Ubuntu.16.04-x64` machine and runs on a raspberry pi 2 (`GNU/Linux 4.1.17-v7+ armv7l`) without installing the dotnet runtime on the PI.

**On the build machine**, Ubuntu.16.04-x64 with `dotnet --version = 2.0.0-preview1-005977`, run the following:

```
mkdir foobar; cd foobar
dotnet new console
dotnet restore -r linux-arm
dotnet publish -r linux-arm
```

This produces a 31MB publish folder with 174 files. Copy those over to the arm device. Note that the resulting executable will not run on the build machine (wrong architecture).

**On the arm device**

First, you have to install some required libraries for the dotnet runtime. 
Unfortunatley this is debian, and probably not suitable for angstrom (this is why I don't mark this as answer).
I picked only non-dev [prerequisites from here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/prereqs.md), since the app is not compiled on the PI.

```
sudo apt-get install libunwind8 libicu52 gettext liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0
```

This list may contain too much / not enough depending on the actual application. Finally, run the self-contained application

```
chmod +x bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/linux-arm/publish/foobar
bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/linux-arm/publish/foobar
```

The execution speed (slow as hell for writing "Hello World!" to the console) indicates that this is actually byte code bootstrapped by some kind of included dotnet clr.

Comment: yeah the problem is that the self-contained distribution is not processed by "crossgen", so it has to do JIT compilation of most of the runtime. When running on a "shared framework" the startup time is much faster.

Comment: This is the other route, I'm following - cross-compiling the CLR for arm. That worked eventually (instructions and build scripts are good), but I'm not sure what to do with the build output... how to "manually" install the CLR into the arm device linux.